# Removing HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, t4

I wasn't entirely sure how to word this in the title, but here's my problem:
I'm utilizing Kendo UI and have a TabStrip object, with different events set to fire when you move to certain tabs. The last tab is a 'Confirm Selections' tab. When this tab is clicked, it grabs selections from previous tabs and displays them one last time for a user to confirm that this is what they want.

I am utilizing T4 templates in order to display the user selections back to them on this screen with this code:

```
<script id="confirmSelections" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <h3>Selected Titles</h3>
    # for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) { #
    <p>Title: #= titles[i] #</p>
    # } #
</script>
```

The only problem is, I've realized that if I move back to any of my previous tabs, and then back to this 'Confirm Selections' tab, it keeps the already created `<p></p>`s and recreates all the HTML elements again. Meaning then, there's duplicates of the same Titles as many times as I move backwards. So, I would like to clear the palette and then recreate the HTML elements every time 'Confirm Selections' is clicked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can store the selection in an Observable object and use the MVVM approach: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/index

Comment: Using these, wouldn't I run into the same issue?

Comment: I don't think so. All the tabs are always present in the DOM. If you bind them all to the same model (or better yet, the container containing the tabs to the model), they will always reflect the changes on the model.

Comment: Show the code where you call confirmSelections. You can clear the html() before that.

Comment: I ended up just setting the innerHTML of the div to the empty string right before setting it to an actual value. I forgot that the innerHTML field existed when I posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#confirmSelections")[0].innerHTML = "";` was used to clear the div each iteration to disable duplicates from making their way into the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to create a wizard or multi step UI. Have a look at [this blog post](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/step-wise-forms-with-asp-net-mvc-and-kendo-ui).